Unexplained, automatically assigned parenting/constraints between objects
I'm encountering a strange issue in Blender. When I move/rotate/scale an object, random objects move along with it but with reduced influence. It's like they inherit the transformations somehow.
What I've checked:

No obvious parenting issues
No constraints detected
Tried Alt + P many times, even on the whole scene by selecting all objects and Alt + P'ing them

These objects seem to have been randomly assigned as if parented or constrained together, and I can't un-parent/clear them. They don't even appear to be parented in the usual way.
And they are many of them in the scene, it's ruining it.
Does anyone know how to clear these relations? I'm willing to clear everything.

pls provide blend file because we can only guess around. Thx for your understanding. Also make sure proportional editing  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/UH82W0ED.png is turned off.

Oh wow ! That was it.
Never suspected that could affect surrounding objects.
That was driving me crazy. Thank you very much !

you are welcome

Take care. Opensource wins !

Make sure Proportional Editing is turned off.
